# Don't understand this E4X behaviour

Tags: apache-flex, e4x

I'm trying to grab a property value of a particular node but getting stumped by its behaviour.

I have this XML in a data provider:

```
<items>
    <item>
        <code>ITEM1</code>
        <groups>
            <group>
                <code>GROUP1</code>
                <props>
                    <prop>
                        <code>PROP1</code>
                    </prop>
                    <prop>
                        <code>PROP2</code>
                    </prop>
                </props>
            </group>
        </groups>
    </item>
    <!-- Lots more items, each item has a variable number of groups and props -->
</items>
```

Now, this code:

```
var itemData:XMLList = dataProvider..elements("item").(code == "ITEM1");
```

successfully returns the 1st `<item>`.

Next, I do:

```
var groupData:XMLList = itemData..elements("group").(code == "GROUP1")
```

But that *doesn't* work. `groupData.length() == 0`

If I drop `elements()`, then it works:

```
var groupData:XMLList = itemData..group.(code == "GROUP1")
```

But I need to use elements() because element names are potentially configurable.

So the question is, why does the first statement work, but using the same statement on the data returned by the first statement failed to work as expected?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to delete the question after getting the answer like previous one?

Comment: Sorry Timofei, I deleted it because I realised the problem was with Flash Builder debug mode. Guess I shouldn't have deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **group** is inner element of **groups** and not direct child of **item**
and second statement is working because of recursive in nature

Try following code

```
var itemData:XMLList = xml..elements("item").(code == "ITEM1"); 
//Alert.show(itemData.toXMLString());
var groupsData:XMLList = itemData..elements("groups");              
//Alert.show(groupsData.toXMLString());
var groupData:XMLList = groupsData..elements("group").(code == "GROUP1")
//Alert.show(groupData.toXMLString());
```

you can enable Altert to see expression result

EDITED Details for element function can be found at
[AS3 XML elements()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#elements%28%29)

hopes that helps

Comment: Doesn't the .. mean descendants? So it should be able to find that "group" is a descendant of "item". Otherwise itemData..group wouldn't work... no?

Comment: hmmm, i think descendant operator **..** is not works/ignored with/before element tag, details about element tag can be found at link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#elements()

Comment: You're right. I changed to use descendants() and it works now. The .. shouldn't be there, even thought the compiler doesn't complain about it.